# Event Handler for Outlook Add-in dialog box is failing

Tags: outlook-web-addins, outlook-2013

I have add-in that calls a dialog box from an Outlook task pane. The Dialog is loading properly but the parent task pane is not receiving any data from the Dialog even though the dialog has the messageParent script on it. It seems that the event handler in the parent task pane is not executing at all.

I am using Outlook 2013 and also via Outlook.com. Both environments are displaying the same behaviour.

**This is the code I have in the parent task pane:**

```
var dlg;
Office.initialize = function (reason) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#btnTestDialog").click(function () {
            Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync("https://localhost:44300/TestDialog.aspx",
                { height: 50, width: 25, displayInIframe: true },
                function (result) {
                    dlg = result.value;
                    dlg.addEventHandler(Microsoft.Office.WebExtension.EventType.DialogMessageReceived, processTestDialog);
                });
        });
    });
};

function processTestDialog(result) {
    var x = "";
    dlg.close();
}
```

**This is my code from my Dialog page (TestDialog.aspx)**

```
Office.initialize = function (reason) {
            $('#btnTest').click(passDataToTest);

            $(document).ready(function () {

            });
        };

        function passDataToTest() {
            var response = { "status": "sucess", "message": "test" };
            Office.context.ui.messageParent(JSON.stringify(response));
        }
```

I have done a lot of research and in all my research it is saying that this code should work but I have no idea why it is not.

Comment: Is the dialog in the same domain as the add-in? (or added to the appdomains section of the manifest). Are there errors returned in console when debugging? 

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/dialog-api-in-office-add-ins

Comment: Yes, they are in the same domain. I am accessing the localhost at the moment.

Comment: We tried this in both outlook.com and Outlook 2013 but could not reproduce the issue.

Comment: I did also try using as much of your code sample as I could to test the functionality. But I couldn't find any error with it. I would just double-check using breakpoints that all of the code leading up to the event firing is getting hit as expected.